# Keypress event listener

Tags: javascript, keypress, event-listener

I am using an event listener to check when values are place into an input, the problem I am getting is that it is only logging the value-1.

```
function init() {
    'use strict';
    document.getElementById("query").addEventListener('keypress', function(){
        var query = document.getElementById("query").value;
        app.request(query);
    }, false);
};
```

If I input abc it will only get ab as the value of the input. Any ideas?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4bhypfqm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using keyup event.

```
function init() {
    'use strict';
    document.getElementById("query").addEventListener('keyup', function(){
        var query = document.getElementById("query").value;
        app.request(query);
    }, false);
};
```